# Getting error while `npm run build`

Tags: nodejs, npm

What may be the issue ?

```
> @ build /home/mafia/repo
> npm run build:src && npm run build:test


> @ build:src /home/mafia/repo
> babel src/main/webapp/js/ -x ".es6" -d src/main/webapp/js/

Error: Cannot find module 'electron-to-chromium' (While processing preset: "/home/mafia/repo/node_modules/babel-preset-env/lib/index.js")
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mafia/repo/node_modules/babel-preset-env/lib/normalize-options.js:11:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-71-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build:src"
npm ERR! node v7.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ build:src: `babel src/main/webapp/js/ -x ".es6" -d src/main/webapp/js/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ build:src script 'babel src/main/webapp/js/ -x ".es6" -d src/main/webapp/js/'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     babel src/main/webapp/js/ -x ".es6" -d src/main/webapp/js/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/mafia/.npm/_logs/2017-04-09T18_06_55_612Z-debug.log

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-71-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v7.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ build: `npm run build:src && npm run build:test`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ build script 'npm run build:src && npm run build:test'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build:src && npm run build:test
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/mafia/.npm/_logs/2017-04-09T18_06_55_684Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems not to be about Ubuntu, but is rather a general programming question.

However, if you actually looked at the output, you would have spotted the line `Cannot find module 'electron-to-chromium'` in there, which clearly indicates that your project is missing the module [electron-to-chromium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-to-chromium) as dependency.

You should be able to install it by running the command below inside your project directory, which also adds the module to the list of dependencies in your `package.json`:

```
npm install --save electron-to-chromium
```